# get my status from facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get my statues from facebook api.
for example:
I post a status on my facebook page:
I love apple.

I need to fetch the data.

I used facebook api.

```
FB.api('/me/feed', function(response)
 {
   //do my process 
 }
```

however, the data I get is in this format

```
data": [
  {
     "id": "*",
     "from": {
        "name": "*",
        "id": "*"
     },
     "story": "* is now friends with \u674e\u7490 and \u9ec4\u68ee\u6d2a.",
     "story_tags": {
        "0": [
           {
              "id": "*",
              "name": "****",
              "offset": 0,
              "length": 9,
              "type": "user"
           }
        ],
        "30": [
           {
              "id": "100003483506950",
              "name": "\u674e\u7490",
              "offset": 30,
              "length": 2,
              "type": "user"
           }
        ],
        "37": [
           {
              "id": "100008056628095",
              "name": "\u9ec4\u68ee\u6d2a",
              "offset": 37,
              "length": 3,
              "type": "user"
           }
        ]
     },
     "privacy": {
        "value": ""
     },
     "type": "status",
     "status_type": "approved_friend",
     "created_time": "2014-03-23T02:10:33+0000",
     "updated_time": "2014-03-23T02:10:33+0000"
  },
```

the things are all about friends approvment, but what I want is my status.
How should I get these information?

Thank you very much.

Chao

Answer (score 0):

The edge {user_id}/feed will return everything that user has done. You can filter down the information returned by adding fields to select what data you want returned.

```
me/feed?fields=status_type
```

The **status_type** argument will return you which type of update it was and you can use that to filter out the updates you don't want.

You can also play around with the arguments at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/